# Apache Http test cases using Junit

Tags: java, junit, mockito, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to write ***unit test*** for a method which uses Apache Http to fetch data.

```
public UserResponse getUserById(String id) {
    UserResponse userResponse;
    String jwtToken = SecurityUtil.getAuthToken();
        try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("%s/users/id/%s".formatted(apiUrl, id));

        httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwtToken);
        httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        logger.info("network call");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
            cloneLoanUserResponse = mapper.readValue(responseString, CloneLoanUserResponse.class);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("API call failed with status code: " + statusCode);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error calling getUserByFinuId due to " + ex);
    }
    return userResponse;
}
```

Here is the test case that I have managed courtesy chatgpt.

```
    @Test
    public void shouldReturnUserById() throws IOException {
        UserResponse expectedResponse = new UserResponse(UUID.fromString("ea9a2ace-7872-4c20-ac7f-37d27b5b657b"), "63b2c4f1c3796b6fc01kebab", "1002");

        CloseableHttpClient httpClientMock = Mockito.mock(CloseableHttpClient.class);
        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponseMock = Mockito.mock(CloseableHttpResponse.class);
        HttpEntity httpEntityMock = mock(HttpEntity.class);
        StatusLine statusLineMock = mock(StatusLine.class);

        when(httpClientMock.execute(any(HttpGet.class))).thenReturn(httpResponseMock);
        when(httpResponseMock.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(statusLineMock);
        when(statusLineMock.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(200);
        when(httpResponseMock.getEntity()).thenReturn(httpEntityMock);
        when(httpEntityMock.getContent()).thenReturn(new ByteArrayInputStream("{\n  \"userId\": \"ea9a2ace-7872-4c20-ac7f-37d27b5b657b\",\n  \"legacyId\": \"645606f1bd069d25b6d0ce59\",\n  \"finuId\": \"645606f1bd069d25b6d0ce59\"\n}".getBytes()));

        // Mock ObjectMapper.readValue()
        ObjectMapper objectMapperMock = mock(ObjectMapper.class);
        when(objectMapperMock.readValue(anyString(), eq(CloneLoanUserResponse.class))).thenReturn(expectedResponse);
        try {
            when(httpClientMock.execute(any(HttpGet.class))).thenReturn(httpResponseMock);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // When
        CloneLoanUserResponse actualResponse = userServiceClient.getUserByFinuId("FINUA0001002");

        // Then
        // Add assertions based on your expected and actual results
        assertEquals(expectedResponse, actualResponse);
    }
```

When I try to run above test case, it makes an http call on a random port but fails to return anything and complete / exit the test.

I am very new to Java and Junit. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your mocking is unfortunately not used, because the method to test creates its own `CloseableHttpClient`. Fortunately, HttpClient has something for this. With these, you can send actual HTTP requests, but to a test server that only exists while each test is running.

### HttpClient 4.x

Since the tags include "apache-httpclient-4.x" I'll that with that.

First you need a dependency with the same version as the HttpClient you're using:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

This gives you access to class `LocalServerTestBase`. This is meant to be extended by your own test classes. If that's not possible you need to create a little helper class that exposes a protected field you need:

```java
final class HttpServer extends LocalServerTestBase {

    ServerBootstrap serverBootStrap() {
        return serverBootstrap;
    }
}
```

If you're using JUnit 4, the `LocalServerTestBase` comes with its own `@Before` and `@After` methods. If you're using JUnit 5 you need to call these explicitly:

```java
// if needed, include this
//private Server server = new Server();

@BeforeEach
protected void startServer() {
    // The setUp method is annotated with JUnit 4's @Before
    assertDoesNotThrow(this::setUp);
}

@AfterEach
protected void shutdownServer() {
    // The setUp method is annotated with JUnit 4's @After
    assertDoesNotThrow(this::shutDown);
}
```

In your test methods you can now register a handler that determines the response:

```java
// use server.serverBootStrap() if you didn't extend LocalServerTestBase
serverBootStrap.registerHandler("/path-to-test", (request, response, context -> {
    // setup your response here
    response.setStatusCode(200);
});
```

After that's done, you must call `start()` (or `server.start()`). That returns an `HttpHost` that you can use to get its port etc. It has method `toURI` that gives you a `URI` if you prefer that.

```java
HttpHost host = assertDoesNotThrow(this::start);
```

Now that you have that, you can set the `apiUrl` of your `userServiceClient`.

If you need the host for the `apiUrl` in your existing `@BeforeEach` method, you can move some stuff around so you can call `server.start()` there. That does mean setting up the handler in your `@BeforeEach` method. That makes it less flexible.

### HttpClient 5.x

HttpClient 5.x has something similar. You again need a dependency with the same version as the HttpClient you're using:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient5-testing</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Unlike HttpClient 4'x `LocalServerTestBase`, HttpClient 5's `ClassicTestServer` was always meant to be included. And unlike `localServerTestBase`, you can register handlers after starting. That makes it simpler to use.

Setup this server in your test class:

```java
private ClassicTestServer server = new ClassicTestServer();
private String hostname;

@BeforeEach
protected void start(TestInfo testInfo) {
    assertDoesNotThrow(() -> server.start());

    InetAddress address = server.getInetAddress();
    // you can now get the port and hostname for the apiUrl from address
    hostname = address.getHostAddress();
}

@AfterEach
protected void shutdown() {
    server.shutdown(CloseMode.GRACEFUL);
}
```

In your test methods you can now register a handler that determines the response:

```java
server.registerHandlerVirtual(hostname, "/path-to-test", (request, response, context -> {
    // setup your response here
    response.setCode(200);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Rob. Do you have any working example of the same for reference?
I am getting this error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.http.impl.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.registerHandler(String, org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestHandler)" because "this.serverBootstrap" is null`

Comment: Did you make sure that the `setUp` method is called? Because that's what should set the `serverBootstrap` variable. As I said, in JUnit 4 it should get called automatically, in JUnit 5 you need to call it yourself.